# Python function output error, Checking an index to see value?

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, indexing

I am building a function that accepts a puzzle= 2d list and checks to make sure every position has a value in it. If it has none in it, then it needs to return false. It should be pretty basic but my function keeps returning True and I cannot understand why.

Example input/expected output:

> is_complete([[1,2,3],[3,1,2],[2,3,1]]) → True
>
> is_complete([[None,None],[None,None]]) → False

My code is as follows:

```
def is_complete(puzzle):
    for row in puzzle:
        for val in row:
            if val == None:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that seems to work with your test input and even with the '[[None]]' as mentioned by [Rolo787](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5156066/rolo787) is as follows. Instead of using 2 for loops, just check if None is in the row.

```
def is_complete(puzzle):
    for row in puzzle:
        if None in row:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function will immediately stop after either return statement. This is why it will return False if the only value passed is '[[None]]'. A solution to this would be to move your 'return True' after all values have been iterated over.

```
def is_complete(puzzle):
    for row in puzzle:
        for val in row:
            if val == None:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: @ocean.1234 I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Your loops are both fine. It's just the fact that you're returning a value after checking the very first index of the very first list passed.

Comment: Yeah if you're checking for specific things being not as desired, you should return when the undesired elements are encountered, and then return `True` **only** after everything has been checked. Because as soon as you return `True` it exits the method before the loop completes.